# Matching two elements in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, match, matching

I have spent this afternoon trying to solve this question:

How can I check if the {from, to} elements in this array are the same? In words: I need to know how to match an array elements in a recursive function.

**Example**

**This array must return FALSE because the $array[4][0]['from'] and $array[4][0]['to'] is NOT the same in all the $array[2] and $array[3].**

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 1
                    [to] => 2.0000
                    [price] => 8.0000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 2.0000
                    [to] => 4.0000
                    [price] => 6.0000
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 1
                    [to] => 3.0000
                    [price] => 70.0000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 3.0000
                    [to] => 5.0000
                    [price] => 60.0000
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 5.0000
                    [to] => 9.0000
                    [price] => 50.0000
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 1
                    [to] => 2.0000
                    [price] => 25.0000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 2.0000
                    [to] => 4.0000
                    [price] => 20.0000
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 4.0000
                    [to] => 6.0000
                    [price] => 15.0000
                )

        )

)
```

**This array must return TRUE because the $array[4][0]['from'] and $array[4][0]['to'] is the same in all the $array[2] and $array[3].**

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 1
                    [to] => 3.0000
                    [price] => 7.0000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 3.0000
                    [to] => 5.0000
                    [price] => 6.0000
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 5.0000
                    [to] => 9.0000
                    [price] => 5.0000
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 1
                    [to] => 3.0000
                    [price] => 70.0000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 3.0000
                    [to] => 5.0000
                    [price] => 60.0000
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 5.0000
                    [to] => 9.0000
                    [price] => 50.0000
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 1
                    [to] => 3.0000
                    [price] => 170.0000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 3.0000
                    [to] => 5.0000
                    [price] => 160.0000
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [from] => 5.0000
                    [to] => 9.0000
                    [price] => 150.0000
                )

        )

)
```

I would like to get as result just a True or False value.

Comment: Perhaps try wording your question a different way. I don't really understand what it is you are looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (not tested, and it is definitely not the best way to do it) :

```
$match = true;

foreach ($main_array as $arrays) 
{
    foreach($arrays as $key => $array)
    {
         $from = $array['from'];
         $to = $array['to'];
         foreach($main_array as $tmp_array)
         {          
             if($tmp_array[$key]['from'] != $from || $tmp_array[$key]['to'] != $to) {               
                $match = false;
                break 3;
             }
         }
    }
}

return $match;
```

Comment: I just tested this and it works, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi @redmoon7777 I have tried your code and seems to me that it doesn't work, mybe I wrong something. Can you tell me where? http://codepad.org/bYA9b3gG thanks

Comment: your mistake is on line 18 it should be foreach($ranges as $tmp_array) not foreach($arrays as $tmp_array)

Answer (score 1):

Here my example, I have tested. Here you can compare array of arrays by customizable fields and customizable $depth

Main function:

```
function array_compare(array $haystack, array $to = array(), array &$matches = array(), $depth = 1)
{
    $total = 0;
    if ($depth === 1) // We're in right depth, let's check the elements
    {
        foreach ($haystack as $key => $value)
        {
            $match = true;
            foreach ($to as $to_key => $to_value) // Check every key
            {
                if (!isset($value[$to_key]) || $value[$to_key] !== $to_value)
                {
                    $match = false; // If at least one doesn't match - break and block adding to $matches
                    break;
                }               
            }
            if ($match)
            {
                $matches[]  = $value; // OK, match, let's add to matches.
            }
            $total++; // Increase total searched elements
        }
    }
    else // We're not on the right depth level
    {
        foreach ($haystack as $key => $value)
        {
            $total += array_compare($value, $to, $matches, $depth - 1); // let's gather into
        }
    }

    return $total; // return total searched
}
```

And here how can you use it:

```
$test = array(
    0   => array(
        0   => array(
            'from'      => 1,
            'to'        => 3,
            'value'     => 25,
        ),
        1   => array(
            'from'      => 1,
            'to'        => 3,
            'value'     => 25,
        )
    ), 
    1   => array(
        0   => array(
            'from'      => 2,
            'to'        => 5,
            'value'     => 25,
        ),
        1   => array(
            'from'      => 1,
            'to'        => 3,
            'value'     => 25,
        )
    ),
    2   => array(
        1   => array(
            'from'      => 1,
            'to'        => 15,
            'value'     => 25,
        )
    ),
);

$matches    = array();
$total = array_compare($test, array('from' => 1, 'to' => 3), $matches, 2);
var_dump($matches, $total);
```

Your true must be in case if count($matches) === $total;

Hope that is exact what you need;